# Images not showing up in Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm having trouble with images not displaying in my heroku app. When I run my server locally on Windows or on Ubuntu 12.04 I can see the images just fine. Here's the image tag I'm using:

```
 <img src="assets/slide (1).jpg" alt="Slide Image">
```

Perhaps I'm just not understanding the asset pipeline completely - should I not reference the image as assets/image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `image_tag` method like this.

```
<%= image_tag "slide (1).jpg", alt: "Slide Image" %>
```

Normal html tag doesn't work, because precompiled assets (images, javascripts, stylesheets) have not same names.